# Matplotlib timedelta set ylim

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a series of graphs which are plotting different days on the x axis and time in minutes on the y axis.
[image]
The graphs all have a different max value and I want to set the ylim to be the same for them. I tried selecting the max value from my pandas dataframe, and setting this as the max using ylim. This gave the error message:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I tried manually setting the limit as 7 as this should keep the visualisation similar to below, but instead I get:
[image]

How can I amend the limits when the y axis is in timedelta and measured in minutes?

Comment: Can we see the relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the 1e11 on the upper left corner of the first plot?
That means the *y*-axis is scaled by 1e11.

Manually setting ylim to 7e11 will most likely give you the desired results.

However, 700000000000 minutes is a *veeery* long time! This might indicate a problem in the calculations. Better check your code for divisions - maybe you divide by some very small numbers. This could also be the reason for the error message you posted.

Comment: Perfect thank you! Seems like I plotted seconds or milliseconds instead of minutes ! I didn't notice because of the 1e11 in the corner. Do you know what that actually stands for?

Comment: 1e11 is called scientific notation and stands for 1 * 10^11 or 10000000000 (a one with 11 zeros). This is the scaling factor of the y axis. So e.g. value 5 on the axis is actually 5 times 1e11 (=5e11 = 5*10^11).